# "Change PC Settings" link doesn't work in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, powershell, windows-8.1-upgrade

Okay, Today I've upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 through Store, the upgrade finished successfully and installed as well,

I tried to open the PC settings from the Charms Bar, when I pressed on "Change PC Settings" link, nothing happened, I've tried re-linking it by this command:

> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xml

It didn't work either.

Comment: I'm actually facing this exact same problem.

Comment: Do you have UAC enabled and at the required setting to use `Windows Store` applications?  Have you also tried to restart?

Comment: @Ramhound UAC is disabled, also I can't find Windows Store, even by searching for it, I've tried restarting several times!

Comment: The `Change PC Settings` is a Modern UI application.  UAC is required to run Modern UI applications.  The reason its not doing anything is because you have UAC disabled.  I had found a link that specifically said that,  mentioned it because I thought it might have been the case, but I didn't keep it.  So if you would, enable UAC, and if it solves the problem I will post an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I've tried enabling UAC, but with no luck!

Comment: Alright; Do you have any application that changes `Windows` in some capacity?  Can you launch any Modern UI application?

Comment: I can launch Mail, Calc, Weather, etc.. but I can't reach the Store or the PC Settings!